# Bind MySQL, Cassandra through Postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, cassandra, binding, wrapper

I have a doubt with this.
I'm using postgres to connect two different databases. I'm already can write in both, I can write in MySQL using the mysql_fdw and also I can write values on Cassandra using the Multicorn fdw, but now the thing is that I want to write on both databases from Postgres.

When I when make **\du** in Postgres I get that the two extensions are loaded *(mysql_fdw and multicorn for cassandra)*, also when I make **select * from information_schema._pg_foreign_servers;** I got the name of both, I already have created the database and table name on MySQL and the keyspace and columnfamily on Cassandra.

My doubt now is how can I connect both to replicate the data?

Comment: You have to create foreign tables for both databases and you will simply use them as they would be local PG tables. But be warned - FDWs sometimes cause problems with memory. Either on "the other" database or on PG. So be careful with really big amounts of data.

Comment: But to create the foreign table I need to specify the servers that it will going to use it right?

Comment: Yes of course but if you want to use mysql_fdw or any other FDW you have to create "Foreign server" and "user mapping" and "foreign tables" as it is described in documentation - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createserver.html So you do this for both FDWs and you get 2 different foreign tables on 2 different foreign servers... But maybe I do not understand you problem properly...

Comment: My problem is that I want to bind data from postgres to mysql and cassandra.
As you said, I'm actually using the mysq_fdw for mysql (properly) and multicorn for cassandra, but I do not know how to bind one foreign table to this 2 servers.

Comment: I check the link you send me, I already create the to servers for mysql and cassandra, but my doubt still going on how I can bind one foreign table to the two servers (mysql and cassandra)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Of course you can bind one foreign table to only one foreign server. So if you want to "replicate" data from PG to both MySQL and Cassandra you have to create foreign table for each remote server separately and insert the same data into both of them.